# checkbox state and other attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

What would be the best way to get the checked or unchecked state of a checkbox + any other relevant data like `data-id` etc

So far I have

```
$(".checkbox").each(function(){
    var $checked = $(":checked");
});
```

I have a var checkbox that is set as an array.  My ideal result would be data-id state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is(":checked")` to see if checkbox is checked. And you can use `.data(key)` to retrieve data attributes.

For example this code will loop thru all checkboxes, collecting their "data-id" values only for checked ones:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) aCheckbox.push($(this).data("id"))
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5AVv/1/